# Clickpocalypse 2 automation script

Tags: javascript

[Clickpocalypse 2](http://minmaxia.com/c2/) is kind of dungeon crawler game but with minor controls. Script's purpose to automate what is left.

To try it out:

1. Open "Clickpocalypse 2" as separate browser window (not a tab, game have to be in active tab to work without delays)
2. Select your party members and let them start palying
3. Paste code in developer tools ([gist](https://gist.github.com/koutoftimer/c497259d270640c00f4bd637b82eeb3a) mirror for faster selection)
4. Execute `turn_on()` and `auto_loot.start()`

```javascript
// Usage: run this script in your browser.
//
// By default it doesn't starts automatically. You have to run `turn_on()` function
// or start each module indivitually `auto_<name>.start()`.
// `turn_off()` and `auto_<name>.stop()` does the oposite.
// `modules_preset` defines set of modules to be handled by `turn_*` functions.

// ------------------------------------------
// --  Utility
// ------------------------------------------

async function sleep(msec) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, msec))
}

class Mutex {
    constructor() {
        this.current = Promise.resolve()
    }
    async lock() {
        let unlock
        const prev = this.current
        this.current = new Promise(resolve => unlock = () => resolve())
        return prev.then(() => unlock)
    }
}

const mutex = new Mutex()

// Manages event queue to let Clickpocalypse 2 engine handle them properly.
async function button_click(button) {
    const unlock = await mutex.lock()
    button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup'))
    await sleep(150)
    unlock()
}

// Decorator class that allows to turn on/off separate modules
class WorkerDecorator {
    #job
    #interval
    #timer
    constructor(job, interval) {
        this.#job = job
        this.#interval = interval
        this.#timer = null
    }
    start() {
        this.#timer = setInterval(this.#job, this.#interval)
    }
    stop() {
        clearInterval(this.#timer)
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------
// --  Set auto looter (1 second interval)
// ------------------------------------------
// Presses loot button.

async function auto_loot() {
    const loot_button = document.querySelector('#treasureChestLootButtonPanel.lootButton')
    if (loot_button) button_click(loot_button)
}
auto_loot = new WorkerDecorator(auto_loot, 1000)

// ------------------------------------------
// --  Set auto upgrader (30 seconds interval)
// ------------------------------------------
// Uses gold, kills and experience to buy upgrades.

async function auto_upgrader() {
    Array.prototype.filter.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('#upgradeButtonContainer .upgradeButton'),
        e => e.style.display == 'block'
    ).forEach(async (e) => await button_click(e))
}
auto_upgrader = new WorkerDecorator(auto_upgrader, 30 * 1000)

// ------------------------------------------
// --  Set auto potion user (30 seconds interval)
// ------------------------------------------
// Waits for all avaliable potion slots to fill up
// before activation.

function auto_potions() {
    const potions = document.querySelectorAll('#potionButtonContainer .potionButton')
    const locked_potions = document.querySelectorAll('.potionButtonLocked').length
    if (potions.length === 8 - locked_potions) {
        potions.forEach(async (e) => await button_click(e.parentNode))
    }
}
auto_potions = new WorkerDecorator(auto_potions, 30 * 1000)

// ------------------------------------------
// --  Set auto skill unlocker (30 seconds interval)
// ------------------------------------------
// Unlocks skills for each hero in order specified
// by strategies.

var auto_skills = function() {

    // Character names - Role:
    // * Hugo - Fighter
    // * Drago - Druid
    // * Meiji - Ninja
    // * Lord Volaille - King
    // * Casey - Rogue

    function get_character_name(id) {
        return document.querySelector(`#characterLevelUpButtonContainer${id}_0 span`)?.textContent.replace('Level Up ', '')
    }

    // List of all skills, top to bottom, left to right.
    const full_skillset = [...Array(4).keys()].map(col => [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, col])).flat()

    // List of skill learning strategies per hero
    // TODO: add more strategies for ommited heroes
    const strategies = {

        'Hugo': [
            // taunt
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 0]),
            // health regen
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 2]),
            // AOE
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 3]),
            // last skills
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 1]),
        ].flat(),

        'Drago': [
            // Minor Heal
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 0]),
            // Guard Dog
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 3]),
            // max wolf pack
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 2]),
            // Sleep
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 1]),
        ].flat(),

        'Meiji': [
            // Swift Strike
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 0]),
            // HP regen
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 2]),
            // Damage
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 1]),
            // Attack speed
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 3]),
        ].flat(),

        'Lord Volaille': [
            // Very first chicken
            [[0, 0]],
            // Guard chicken
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 1]),
            // Chicken chance: Rouge
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 0]).slice(1),
            // Chicken chance: Ninja
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 2]),
            // Chicken chance: Barbarian
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 3]),
        ].flat(),

        'Casey': [
            // Detect Treasure Chest
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 3]),
            // Loot instantly
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 2]),
            // Improve health
            [...Array(9).keys()].map(row => [row, 1]),
            // Skip stealth
            [...Array(4).keys()].map(row => [row, 0]),
        ].flat(),

    }

    return async function() {

        // `id` is a positional index of the hero in the party composition
        const locked_hero_slots = document.querySelectorAll('.gameTabLockedAdventurerInfo').length
        for (let id of Array(5 - locked_hero_slots).keys()) {

            // skip hero if he has no free skill points
            if (!document.querySelector(`#gameTabMenu li:nth-child(${id + 4}).tabHighlighted`)) {
                continue
            }

            // select skillset tab for current hero
            document.querySelector(`#gameTabMenu li:nth-child(${id + 4}) > a`).click()
            // let Clickpocalypse 2 engine update skillset DOM
            await sleep(200)

            // TODO: cache this value over id
            let strategy
            const name = get_character_name(id)
            if (!Object.hasOwn(strategies, name)) {
                strategy = full_skillset
                console.warn(`Custom strategy for [${name}] not found. Using default one.`)
            } else {
                strategy = strategies[name]
            }

            for (let [row, col] of strategy) {
                const skill = document.getElementById(`characterSkillsContainer${id}_${row}_${col}_${row}`)
                // some characters have incompleate skill table
                // ensure we have met requirements to learn this skill
                if (skill?.classList.contains('upgradeButton')) {
                    await button_click(skill)  // dead-lock
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        // go back to Game screen
        document.querySelector('#gameTabMenu li:nth-child(3) > a').click()
    }
}()
auto_skills = new WorkerDecorator(auto_skills, 30 * 1000)

// auto_loot helpfull for early game or if you have no Rouge in the party
const modules_preset = [auto_skills, auto_potions, auto_upgrader]

// Bot (automation) switch handlers
function turn_on() {
    for (const worker of modules_preset) {
        worker.start()
    }
}

function turn_off() {
    for (const worker of modules_preset) {
        worker.stop()
    }
}
```